# Handbrake x264 encodes .m4v/.mp4 not accepted in iTunes

Tags: itunes, mp4, h.264

It seems like every once in awhile, when using Handbrake to encode a DVD rip to x264 with either the mp4 or m4v extension, I can't add the resulting file to my iTunes Library. When dragging and dropping, the Library window highlights like it's going to accept (If you try to drag an unsupported file, the window doesn't highlight, and the thumbnail you're dragging flies back to the original folder).

If I rip a handful of movies and do an overnight encode session, in the morning some of the files can be added to the library, some can't. I have to re-do the ones that don't work.  Is there a way to found out what the problem is? An iTunes setting that will output what it doesn't like about certain files? A piece of software that can validate the files?  The resulting files play in VLC and Quicktime Player regardless of if they're added to my iTunes Library.

Comment: What handbrake encoding profile are you using?

Comment: Turns out it was a glitch in iTunes, I restarted my Mac and the movies were in the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handbrake keeps individual logs for every encode. You can find them in `~/Library/Application Support/HandBrake/EncodeLogs`.

If an encode fails, it should contain any relevant information on why it failed.

Comment: Encoding didn't fail, the movies could be watched in Quicktime. After restarting iTunes, each movie I dragged to the Library was now present in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Handbrake 0.9.9 (64 bit)** on **OS X 10.8.4** with **iTunes 11.0.4**, I encoded the same movie using the **AppleTV 2** *preset* and the iPhone's.  It successfully encoded the movie, generating two *.m4v* files on my desktop. I couldn't, though, *Add To Library* nor drag and drop into the library. They would play fine in QuickTime.

The solution was dead simple, rename them to .mov files.

*Voilà*, everything worked.